# How to input power in Python

Tags: python

So I am trying to get the correct answer, but I think the way I am using my power is messing the equation up. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Prompt the user to enter three numbers
finalaccountvalue = eval(input("Final Account Value: "))

annualinterestrate = eval(input("Annual Interest Rate: "))

numberofyears = eval(input("Number of Years: "))

# Compute initial deposit amount
initialdepositamount = (finalaccountvalue) / ((1 + annualinterestrate)**numberofmonths)

# Display result
print("The final account value", finalaccountvalue, "with the annual interest rate", annualinterestrate, "for the duration in years", numberofyears, "would have an initial deposit amount", initialdepositamount)
```

They say to use 1000 for final account value, 4.25 for interest rate, and number of years 5. The answer should be 808.8639.... but I am getting 0.25072....

Comment: `eval` with input? A big **NO**.

Comment: Where is `numberofmonths` defined?

Comment: @Kevin, I changed the "numberofyears" to "numberofmonths". but I am still not getting the correct answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percentages in formulas are typically supposed to be represented as a number between 0 and 1. Entering 4.25 here is effectively calculating the deposit amount for an account with 425% interest. Try dividing the annual interest rate by 100 before using it in your formula. Also, where possible, use regular type conversion instead of `eval`.

```
finalaccountvalue = float(input("Final Account Value: "))
annualinterestrate = float(input("Annual Interest Rate: ")) / 100.0
numberofyears = int(input("Number of Years: "))
initialdepositamount = (finalaccountvalue) / ((1 + annualinterestrate)**numberofyears)
print("The final account value", finalaccountvalue, "with the annual interest rate", annualinterestrate, "for the duration in years", numberofyears, "would have an initial deposit amount", initialdepositamount)
```

Result:

```
Final Account Value: 1000
Annual Interest Rate: 4.25
Number of Years: 5
The final account value 1000.0 with the annual interest rate 0.0425 for the duration in years 5 would have an initial deposit amount 812.1190197993631
```

But I notice that 812.12 doesn't quite match your expected value of 808.86. Did you intend to apply the interest every month, instead of every year?

```
finalaccountvalue = float(input("Final Account Value: "))
annualinterestrate = float(input("Annual Interest Rate: ")) / 100.0
numberofyears = int(input("Number of Years: "))
initialdepositamount = (finalaccountvalue) / ((1 + annualinterestrate/12.0)**(numberofyears*12))
print("The final account value", finalaccountvalue, "with the annual interest rate", annualinterestrate, "for the duration in years", numberofyears, "would have an initial deposit amount", initialdepositamount)
```

Result:

```
Final Account Value: 1000
Annual Interest Rate: 4.25
Number of Years: 5
The final account value 1000.0 with the annual interest rate 0.0425 for the duration in years 5 would have an initial deposit amount 808.8639197424636
```